# spresense arduino IDEでリアルタイムで自前の画像認識（正解画像と不正解画像）するスケッチを作成したい

Tags: spresense, arduino

SONY NNC window版で自前の画像（ラズパイＶ２）80×80、datesets positiveとnegative画像をそれぞれ、120枚と90枚で学習して、28×28サイズで学習結果　accuracy=1を得て、model.nnbをSDに保存。この作業のまえに、NNCクトプロジェクト例のnummber_recognition.sdcprjの学習済みmodel.nnb をSDカードに保存後、Spresense arduino IDEのスケッチ例、Spresense_number_recognition.inoを試した結果数字の認識が再現出来ましたので、これを手本に、
下記の様にコード変えてみましたが、
・・・・・
画像サイズが28×28の偶数倍の正□角した
#define DNN_IMG_W 28
#define DNN_IMG_H 28
#define CAM_IMG_W 320
#define CAM_IMG_H 240
#define CAM_CLIP_X ***40***
#define CAM_CLIP_Y 0
#define CAM_CLIP_W **224**
#define CAM_CLIP_H 224
・・・・・
static uint8_t const label[**2**] = {**" *positve_20pg, negative_20pg* "**};
・・・・・
if (index < ***1***) {
gStrResult = String(label[index]) + String(":") + String(output[index]);
} else {
gStrResult = String("?:") + String(output[index]);
}
・・・・・
以上3か所で
書き込みすると、下部のライン表示部は
71：0.00で点滅で同じ数字で、入力画像を変えても変化しない結果、

以上の3か所はほかのにも試しましたが同じ結果でした、
おそらく、ほかに変える必要あるところは、
labelがposiとnegaの2種類ですので、上記でよいと思いますが、
どこをどう直せばよいのか？
画像の判定評価の結果の確立がposiの時は0.9900以上あり、negaの時は0.001以下ですので、この評価が必要と思いますが、コードの書き方が分からないので、
他に、2種類の判定するスケッチの例（例：リンゴとオレンジの画像を識別するスケッチ）識別するものあれば教えてもらえませんか？

Comment: えっと０からすべて教えてくださいってこと？　おそらく本が数冊書けるくらいの分量になるので、こういうQ&Aサイトでは時間的にも分量的にも不可能です。もっと範囲を絞って、ここがわからないのように訊いてください。

Comment: まずシステム構成はどうなっていますか？あと、うまくいかなかったスケッチを記載し、どのような結果もしくはエラーメッセージが出たかを記載していただければ何かアドバイスできるかも知れません。この情報だけでは、何をもって”うまくいかなかった”と判断したのか分からないのでアドバイスのしようがありません。あと、プログラミングの知識ありなしは質問には関係ないです。”プログラミングの知識がない”と自分からアピールされてしまっては、回答できる人も回答に躊躇してしまいます。せっかく新しいことにチャレンジされているのにもったいないです。適切な質問することは技術力とは関係ありませんしね。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます、よくわかりましたので、投稿で再度もっと内容を絞り込み、詳しく行ったことを説明して、出来なかったことを具体的に説明します。

Comment: Spresense_number_recognition.ino がどういうものかわからないのでスケッチ全体を貼り付けたほうがよいですね。後、シリアルコンソールの出力もそのまま掲載したほうがよいと思います。７１：０．００点滅ということの意味がよくわかりません。

Comment: 依頼の件で、スケッチ全体を貼り付けましたが、too longでコメント追加できません、
どうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: 依頼のスケッチ全体を貼り付けしたが、too longでコメントできませんでした、シリアルコンソール出力は71:0.00のみ繰り返し表示されてます、スケッチ全体の件は別でメールで配信する方法は取れませんか？

Comment: スケッチをGithubにあげてそこのリンクを貼り付けるのがよいと思います。Githubが何かわからない場合は、よい機会ですのでGoogle検索などで使い方を覚えてください。シリアルコンソールの出力の 71:0.00の前半については、そもそもlabel文字列のメモリ確保がおかしいところが原因です。そこだけは回答として出すことができますね。やはりC言語の基本がわかっておられないようです。もう少し勉強をされたほうがよいですね。

Answer (score 0):

コンソール文字列の ”71:0.00” 最初の71と表示されてしまうところはラベル文字列用のメモリが確保できていないことが原因です。後半の確率出力はこの内容ではわかりません。

そもそも文字列の定義の部分がおかしいです。

```
static uint8_t const label[2] = {" positve_20pg, negative_20pg "};
```

恐らく、"positive_20pg", "negative_20pg"と２つの文字列を出したいのだと思いますが、その場合はそれぞれの文字列分のメモリを確保する必要があります。"positive_20pg"が13文字、"negative_20pg"が13文字ですので、null終端を考慮し、14文字の配列を確保しておけばよいでしょう。あと文字列ですので uint8_t ではなく char のほうがふさわしいですね。

```
static char const label[2][14] = { "positive_20pg","negative_20pg" };
```

これを次のコードで出力できるか確認してください。

```
static char const label[2][14] = { "positive_20pg","negative_20pg" };

void setup () {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println(label[0]);
  Serial.println(label[1]);
  
}

void loop () {}
```

もし、これで何を言っているのかわからない場合は、**C言語のメモリ配列**について勉強をしてください。CやC++言語の基本中の基本ですので、まずその理解を深めておかないと、この先マイコンボードを扱うことはできません。

あと蛇足ですが、

```
if (index < 1) {
gStrResult = String(label[index]) + String(":") + String(output[index]);
}
```

だと、"positive_20pg" しか表示されませんが、それでいいのでしょうか？もし、そうであれば、わざわざ labelを定義する必要もない気がします。

Comment: 指摘してもらった内容をTRYしても、やはり、C++言語の基本がわかっていないので、せっかくの回答も無駄になることが分かりましたので、これで打ち切りたいと思います、大変な時間を取らせてしまい、本当にすみませんでした、C＋＋言語（arduino IDEのプログラミングの基本）を勉強してから、またTRYします。